# How do I expand my tkinter window properly?

Tags: python, tkinter, window, expand

I want the whole thing to expand, as the user expands it, without widgets, like the listbox, reshaping. I want it to be exactly like expanding a still image which maintains its aspect ratio. How do I do this?

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from random import *
import threading

selected = 0

contained = {}
contained[0] = []

name = {}

maxEventItems = 100

i = 0
while i < 10 ** 3:
    contained[0].append(i)
    name[i] = 'Event {}'.format(i)

    i += 1

# Beginning of thread part, in the future.
def eventViewerListboxItems():
    i = 0
    while i < len(contained[selected]):
        eventNumber = contained[selected][i]

        eventViewerListbox.insert(END,'{}'.format(name[eventNumber]))

        i += 1

master = Tk()

masterCanvas = Canvas(master)
masterCanvas.grid(row = 0,column = 0,sticky = N + S + E + W)

masterFrame = Frame(masterCanvas)
masterFrame.grid(row = 0,column = 0)

main = Frame(masterFrame)
main.grid(row = 0,column = 0)

topButtons = Frame(main)
topButtons.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

saveButton = Button(topButtons,text = 'Save')
saveButton.grid(row = 0,column = 0,sticky = W)

loadButton = Button(topButtons,text = 'Load')
loadButton.grid(row = 0,column = 1,sticky = W)

createEventButton = Button(topButtons,text = 'Create event')
createEventButton.grid(row = 0,column = 2,sticky = W)

eventViewer = Frame(main)
eventViewer.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

eventViewerListboxScrollbar = Scrollbar(eventViewer)
eventViewerListboxScrollbar.grid(row = 1,column = 1, sticky = W + N + S)

eventViewerListbox = Listbox(eventViewer)
eventViewerListbox.grid(row = 1,column = 0,sticky = W)

eventViewerListbox.config(yscrollcommand = eventViewerListboxScrollbar.set)
eventViewerListboxScrollbar.config(command = eventViewerListbox.yview)

bottomButtons = Frame(main)
bottomButtons.grid(row = 2, column = 0,sticky = E)

simulateButton = Button(bottomButtons,text = 'Simulate')
simulateButton.grid(row = 0,column = 0,sticky = E)

callEventViewerListboxItems = threading.Thread(target = eventViewerListboxItems)
callEventViewerListboxItems.start()

partial_contained = {}
partial_contained[selected] = []
i = 0
while i < maxEventItems and i < len(contained[selected]):
    partial_contained[selected].append(contained[selected][i])
    i += 1

print('I started putting the items from contained[{}] into the listbox in the event viewer.'.format(contained[selected][0]))
print()

print('Below, I will show the first {} items that are in contained:'.format(i,contained[selected]))
print(partial_contained[selected])
print()

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand this phrase: "without widgets, like the listbox, reshaping". What do you want to expand? The listbox? Everything but the listbox?

Comment: Everything, but notice when the listbox expands it reshapes slightly. It's not like a still image.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using grid, but you haven't given a weight to any rows or columns. The weight determines which rows and columns are given extra space such as when a user resizes the window. By default the weight of every row and column is zero, meaning they get no extra weight.

As a rule of thumb, you need to call `grid_rowconfigure` and `grid_columnconfigure` for at least one row and one column, and give that row or column a positive weight. You will need to do this for every widget that is using grid to manage its children.

You also aren't using the `sticky` attribute consistently, so even if you get the columns to grow and shrink, your widgets won't expand to fill the area they've been given.

You need to be methodical about creating a complex layout. My advice is to start over, and just get `masterCanvas` to grow and shrink like you expect. Give it a bold, distinctive cover so you can see it (ie: if it has the same color as the background, it's impossible to know if it's growing or shrinking to fill the area)

Once you get `masterCanvas` where it is growing and shrinking properly, move on to `masterFrame`, and then `main`, and then `eventViewer`, and finally the listbox. At each step be sure to give the widget a distinctive color so you can visualize it.

You might also want to consider removing so many layers of nested frames. The more you have, the more difficult it becomes to get them to all work together. However, multiple areas are easy if you take a methodical approach, and don't try to get half a dozen different frames working together all at once. Get one working, then focus on its immediate children. When they work, focus on their children, and so on.